# Python matrix and implementing Gram-Schmidt procedure

Tags: python, matrix, svd

I am supposed to generate a random 40 x 40 matrix A with exponentially graded singular values defined as 2^-1 2^-2...2^-40. How do I go about doing this? it says that np.linalg.qr is useful. 
I was thinking about doing 
np.random.rand(40,40) but i don't know how to make the diagonals ascending exponentially

And then it says to implement Gradm-Schmidt process
Help!

Comment: As far as the math goes, it would be easier to write D = 2^-1...2^-40 as a 40x40 diagonal matrix and generate random unitary U and V. Multiply them to get the "original" matrix required.As for the programming, what have you tried?

Comment: I was thinking about defining projection and then finding the orthonormal vectors for each vector in matrix A

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment, so I'll leave this here even though its not a real answer.

If you first generate a random 40x40 matrix, there is no way to force it into having the eigen values you want. Instead it will be easier to work backwards from the diagonalization. You are given the eigenvalues, just make some random eigenvectors and recalculate the matrix.

Since you are given **distinct** eigenvalues \mu_i = 2^-i, you know the eigenvectors span R^40. I would personally take the 40x40 identity matrix and randomly rotate it to make U then do A=UDU*. Where D_{ij} = \delta_{ij}\mu_i

If you are required to use Gram-Schmidt, you can instead generate 40 random linearly-independent vectors and Gram-Schmidt them to obtain U.